# Transit through Serbia on Pakistani Passport with valid US and UK visas

Tags: transit, pakistani-citizens, serbia

I have a Pakistani Passport which has valid USA and UK multiple entry visas on it. Am I allowed to enter or transit through Serbia particularly Belgrade.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can enter or transit through Belgrade airport or  enter any Serbian Port of Entry without any visa.

From the official **[Ministry Of Foreign Affairs of the Republic Of Serbia](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime)** website:

> At its meeting of 30 October 2014, the Government of the Republic of
>   Serbia adopted the Decision on visa free entry to the Republic of
>   Serbia for holders of foreign passports having a valid Schengen, UK
>   and other Member States' visa, or visa of the United States of
>   America, and for holders of foreign passports having residence permit
>   in the countries of the Schengen area, EU or the United States of
>   America, which was published in the "Official Gazette of RS", No. 119
>   of 31 October 2014 and which will enter into force on 8 November 2014.
>
> By this decision, the above-mentioned categories of foreign nationals
>   may, without prior visa application, enter transit or stay in the
>   Republic of Serbia up to 90 days during a six-month period, but not
>   exceeding the expiring date of the said visas or residence permits.